# How to add parameters when using url_for with an ActiveModel instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemodel

I want to add a parameter when linking to objects of various kinds.

I know I can pass an ActiveModel instance to [url_for](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/url_for) to generate the appropriate URL:

```
url_for(@my_object) # => /my_objects/1
```

But when I try to add parameters to the generated URL, no dice.

```
url_for(@my_object, foo: 'bar') # => ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)
```

Right now I use `url_for(@my_object) + '?foo=bar'` but it's ugly and fragile, and I'd love to find a cleaner/railsier solution.

Answer (score 2):

Haha! While searching the docs to link to the relevant API, I found that `url_for` uses **[polymorphic_path](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html)** under the hood, which does just what I need and accepts additional parameters as a last argument.

I can now replace

```
url_for(@my_object) + '?foo=bar' # Don't do this
```

with the much more robust expression

```
polymorphic_path(@my_object, foo: 'bar')  # This is much better
polymorphic_url(@my_object, foo: 'bar') # Or this for a full URL
```